# Не передается дата из элемента p:calendar

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Пытаюсь передать введенную дату из элемента p:calendar в бин.

Код

```
<h:form id="historyfrm">        
    <p:panel style="margin-left:33%; text-align:center; width:34%">
        <f:facet name="header" >
            Выбор периода
        </f:facet>  

        <p:outputLabel for="mask1" value="Начало: " />
            <p:calendar id="mask1" value="#{hB.period01}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />                                   
        <p:outputLabel for="mask2" value="Окончание: " style="margin-left:20px;"/>
            <p:calendar id="mask2" value="#{hB.period02}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />               
        <p:commandButton id="periodbtn" value="Задать период"  actionListener="#{hB.loadEv}" style="margin-left:30px;" styleClass="ui-state-active"/>               
    </p:panel>    
</h:form>
```

В бине

```
private Date period01;
private Date period02;

public void loadEv() {
        //System.out.println(period01);
        System.out.println("loadEv");
    }

// get set
```

Если в календаре ничего не выбирать, то по нажатию на кнопку попадаем в обработчик (поля равны null), но при выборе любого значения в обработчик не попадаю и поля тоже не заполняются.

Comment: Ваш пример - рабочий (даты заполняются, метод вызывается), но приведён не весь код страницы и бина. Есть вероятность того, что проблемный участок не приведён в вопросе. Удалите со страницы и из бина всё, что не относится к исследуемой проблеме и проверьте заново. Если не поможет - приведите полный текст исходников страницы и бина

Comment: Создал новую страницу и новый бин, начал добавлять по блокам код из старых файлов и проверять работоспособность, в конце получилось полное копирование, все заработало, в чем была проблема, так и не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что использовался класс Date из пакета java.sql, а Primefaces знает только из пакета java.util